# Euro-sign in ggplot: scales package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've noticed that, using the `scales` package, one can display dollars on an axis, using the `scales = dollar` option inside, for instance, `scale_y_log10()`. An option like `scales = euro` seems to be lacking. Is there an easy way for me to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easy to modify dollar_format and change the symbol to euro. Run this and put it in the code like you would call `dollar_format`

```
euro_format <- function(largest_with_cents = 100000) {
  function(x) {
    x <- round_any(x, 0.01)
    if (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) < largest_with_cents &
        !all(x == floor(x), na.rm = TRUE)) {
      nsmall <- 2L
    } else {
      x <- round_any(x, 1)
      nsmall <- 0L
    }
    str_c("€", format(x, nsmall = nsmall, trim = TRUE, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE, digits=1L))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine! For those still confused, you would need to have the `reshape` and `stringr` packages loaded, in addition to `ggplot` and `scales`, to make this work.

Comment: On a limited testing, I found the following worked, which only relies on ``ggplot2`` and ``scales``:  ``euroFrance <- function(x) {
paste0(format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", trim = TRUE,
scientific = FALSE)," €") } ``  (where I have selected French styles to contrast with Luciano's example and show the range of possibilities). Or to say it differently, if you don't need to worry about rounding or trimming decimals, a simple function will do. Oh and you would call it thus: ``+ scale_y_continuous(labels = euroFrance, breaks = etc.``

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `prefix` and `suffix` arguments of `dollar_format`

For example like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)       
ggplot(diamonds) + geom_point(aes(x = carat, y =  price)) + 
   scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(suffix = "€", prefix = ""))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error along the lines of `Not all of the characters in ~/R/stuff.Rmd could be encoded using ISO8859-1. To save using a different encoding, choose "File | Save with Encoding..." from the main menu.` What encoding would you suggest for your solution?

Comment: @DaveRGP  i recomend using `scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(suffix = "\u20AC", prefix = "")` and `ggsave(file = "test.pdf", encoding = "ISOLatin9.enc")`